# openshift mongo mms cannot be embedded in scalable app

Tags: openshift, mongodb-mms

It appears mongo mms cartridge cannot be installed in a scaled app in OpenShift. Is there a way around this limitation? So that you can have database monitoring on a scaled app in OpenShift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this might be a bug so I went ahead and opened one here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1115539. We'll try to get this resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks...Hopefully it won't take too long to fix. We are waiting for this to be working before opening up our live instance.